# Hibernate mapping entity with a Set of itself

Tags: java, database, hibernate, dictionary, many-to-many

I have this class in my code

```
@Entity(name = "Point")
@Table(name = "Point")
public class Point extends com.lsikh.unlmaps.base.Entity<Integer>{
    private Integer id;
    ...
    ...
    private Set<Point> connections = new HashSet<Point >();
```

I need to relate a Point entity with many other Point's object in that Set and retrieve.

This are my tables in the database

```
  CREATE
    TABLE Point(
        id INTEGER UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        ...
        ...
        PRIMARY KEY (id )
    );

CREATE
    TABLE Connections(
        idA INTEGER NOT NULL,
        idB INTEGER NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (idA ) REFERENCES Point (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (idB ) REFERENCES Point(id)
    );
```

Which is the correct set of hibernate notations to do this.
I think could be

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "Connections", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
                    @JoinColumn(name = "idA") })
    public Set<Point> getConnections() {
        return connections;
    }
```

But I'm having problems to do the map and I'm not sure.

Comment: "I'm having problems" is normally a good hint to start telling us _which_ problems you are having (i.e. exceptions you get, what you expect and what you get instead etc. - also see [ask]).

Comment: Side note: beware of `FetchType.EAGER`. Doing it like in your question could cause _all_ points to be loaded, i.e. when you load one point, the system will eagerly load the connected points as well as the points connected to the connected points etc. etc. etc. - it will load _all_ points somehow connected to that single point you were interested in.

Comment: Thanks for that appreciation @Thomas, that's my intention cause I intented to do a graph and need to manipulate all points

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadoc the `joinColumns`:

> The foreign key columns of the join table which reference the primary
>   table of the entity owning the association

So assuming that `idA` is the id of the owning entity in the join table the mapping should be:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "Connections", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "idA") }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
                @JoinColumn(name = "idB") })
public Set<Point> getConnections() {
    return connections;
}
```